# Три основные/основных персонажа

Tags: падежи, прилагательные

Напомните, пожалуйста, правило.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если род мужской или средний, то правильно "основных":
***Три основных персонажа.*** || Мужской род.
*Три основных правила.

Три основных предмета.

Три основных кармана.

Три основных ингредиента.*

Если род женский, то правильно "основные":
*Три основные комнаты.

Три основные чашки.

Три основные линии.*

При существительных мужского и среднего рода, зависящих от числительных два, три, четыре, определение, находящееся между числительным и существительным, ставится, как правило, в форме родительного падежа множественного числа: *два высоких дома, три больших окна*. Например: *Два других кадровика воевали меньше; Три крайних окна на первом этаже закрыты изнутри.*

При существительных женского рода в указанных условиях определение ставится, как правило, в форме именительного падежа множественного числа: *две большие комнаты*.
Например: *По этим дорогам двигаются две большие группы немцев.*
На форму определения может оказать влияние форма сказуемого:
*Разыграны три золотые медали.

Разыграно три золотых медали.*

Розенталь: http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm

Comment: *Если род женский, то правильно "основные".* Не всегда.

Comment: А я и не утверждаю, что всегда. Там по ссылке у Розенталя есть исключение про ударение на Ы.

Comment: Дело не в Ы. Рук**и**, щек**и**, м**е**ста — смысл в том, что ударение меняется.

Comment: Ну да. Только вот у места уже средний род.

Comment: Точно! С местом промах вышел. :)

Answer (score 1):

Это родительный падеж:

> три (кого?) основн**ых** персонажа.

Странно, что вы вариант "основные" пытались согласовать с "персонаж**а**". Если бы это было возможно, должны были бы быть "персонаж**и**".

Comment: Вопрос не исключает и именительного падежа.

Comment: Спасибо Олиду, всё перепутал, исправил теперь ответ.

Comment: _Основные три персонажа находятся в родстве с двумя эпизодическими._ Как этот случай классифицировать?

Comment: Да, тут, и правда, "основные" получается в именительном, а "персонажа" в родительном.

Comment: "Как этот случай классифицировать?" — Очень просто. Розенталь вам в помощь. **Если определение стоит перед счетным оборотом, то оно ставится в форме именительного падежа независимо от рода имени существительного**: *каждые два часа, последние два предложения, лучшие две песни*. Например: *Первые три года она только урывками наезжала в Заболотье* (Салтыков-Щедрин); *Последние два слова были написаны крупным и размашистым, решительным почерком* (Тургенев); *Остальные три лошади... шли сзади* (Шолохов). Но это кроме слов *целый, полный, добрый* и некоторых других.